# Ajax problems with MySQL connection and PHP session

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, session

I've encountered a problem. In my `index.php` I establish a connection to a MySQL database and start a session containing `$_SESSION['name']` and `$_SESSION['password']`.

I include the page content.php into a DIV with PHPs include(). Now I want to refresh the content without reloading the page so I load content.php again via Ajax through jQuerys `load()`. content.php now displays a ton of errors because it cannot connect to the database and doesn't have the session information. Is there a possibility to have the load() function in jQuery work like `include()` in PHP?

I hope someone can help me.

Best regards,

Matteo

Comment: did you call session_start(); in content.php?
also.. you probably need to establish a database connection in content.php aswell ;)

Answer (score 4):

Make a file containing your initialization code, with session_start() and your mysql connection. Then, include it in your index.php and in your content.php. Do it with **include_once** or **require_once**, and it will work in both cases (at first load and at ajax loads).

**init.php**

```
<?php
// Start or retrieve the session
session_start();

// Your connection to mysql
...
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
// Init actions
include_once "init.php";

// Your code
....
?>
```

**content.php**

```
<?php
// Init actions
include_once "init.php";

// Your code
....
?>
```

With this code, first time you include content.php, the call for init.php will be ignored (because it was already included by index.php), and when you call content.php from ajax, it will include your session and database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess. The index.php is what hold the mysql connection right?

If soo.. Then when you do a ajax call to the content.php which then expects a connection as it's set in the index.php it won't retrieve it as it's a new request.

You could move your mysql connection from index.php to content.php OR add a parameter to the ajax call and then check in content.php if that parameter is set. If it is make a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required files included in the content.php file? You will still need all of your database connections declared in this file on top of calling `session_start()` too.

Comment: If I call session_start() will I have the values from the "parent" file or do I have to declare $_SESSION['name'] again?

Comment: @Matteo - You have to use `session_start()` whenever you want to use `$_SESSION` variables. And it will not overwrite existing values until you do it by setting `$_SESSION['var_name']="something" .